# In Windows, what are the possible places the JVM might get the default time zone from?

Tags: windows, java

I'm in a situation where I need to create a UAT environment which mirrors the production environment as closely as possible.

I currently have a problem with a Java application using a different time zone in the two environments, therefore behaving differently.

I know that the JVM lets me pass in e.g. "-Duser.timezone=JST" on the command line. In Windows, what are the possible places where the JVM might get this time zone if not passed to it explicitly (or programatically)?

In case it matters, I am using Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2, and Java 1.5.0_06, but I don't want to limit answers to these environments.

Comment: The Time Zone is generally set via the Date and Time Control Panel applet. Have you tried ensuring both systems have the same TZ selected? Is your Java app still using different TZs despite doing this?

Comment: @Karan, thanks. Does that applet change something in the jre installation itself, or something on the machine (i.e. registry/system locale etc). I am using the exact same installation (same actual files, on a shared drive), but the TZ behavior is different.

Comment: Windows knows nothing about Java or JRE.

Comment: @Karan, maybe not, but jre might be looking at something in Windows when deciding which TZ to start up with.

Comment: Naturally JRE is checking some Windows setting and not vice versa. I was responding to your "Does that applet change something in the jre installation itself" question. You didn't answer whether the same TZ is selected on both systems or not.